# Run Multiple Macros At Different Set Time Intervals vba via button to start- button to stop

Tags: vba

i currently have 5 macros, they refresh my data, macro1 refresh data from sheet1, macro2 refreshes data from sheet2 and so on untill sheet5, each sheet has its own macro to refresh its own sheets data. So what i need is when marco1 starts, wait one minute before running macro2, "macro2 finishes", waite one minute before runing macro3 ans so on till last macro, then i can start the sequence, or stop it an any time via the buttons.  It is data from the web in excel, i have tried going to table properties but have been unable to refresh all 5 tables at time intervals as explained previously.
Any help here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, please:

```
Sub testMacro1()
  'your code here
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "testMacro2"
End Sub
Sub testMacro2()
  'your code here
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "testMacro3"
  MsgBox "Macro2"
End Sub
Sub testMacro3()
  'your code here
  MsgBox "Macro3"
End Sub
```

It will run 'testMacro2' after a minute, then 'testMacro3' after another minute. You can extrapolate the idea up to your 'Macro5' `Sub`...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried placing the code and modifying it as i need but i think it may not work for the click event of the button, to run all five macros at time intervals, perhaps i should place the code on another event?

Comment: @hugo: You did not post anything from your code... Should I understand that the five macros in discussion are not macros, they are code inside events? Can you post the code for two such 'macros'? If it is a matter of events, you can create simple `Subs` in a module and call them from these events... An event macro can also be called, but in a more complicated way. So, making the long story shorter, can you edit your question and post (the relevant part of) the code for such two macros which must consecutively run, after one minute?

Comment: @hugo: If we are talking about a `Click` event of the button, it should work, if the other macros are subs inside a module or even inside a form module where the control with the `Click` event exists. So, please explain in more details the situation from this point of view.

Comment: Ok, i was doing it wrong thanks to your solution it worked, thank you very much, you just saved me who know how many days of google searching for a solution, again, thank you much.

Comment: i was able to put all macros in the same butoons click event.

Comment: @hugo:  Glad I could help! But we here, when a solution helped us to solve our problem, tick the left code side check box to make it the **accepted answer**. In such a way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code worked...

Comment: Do you know how do i place a couple  of beeps, perhaps 3 beeps at the end of the last macro to alert me sequence is done, i have a timer that starts at the beginning of the sequence but it kind of conflicts with the already macro running and don want to end up with unreliable data, so maybe something like a timer or something that identifies the last macro running and when finished it throws a couple of beeps through pc speakers.

Comment: sorry just read your last note, looking for the left code side to make it accepted

Comment: @hugo:  Left side of my code answer... Just bellow the arrows to vote up/down.

Comment: @hugo:  I had the impression that you marked it as accepted answer. Did you change your mind in the meantime? Do you need some more assistance in its implementation?

Comment: @hugo: Now I could see your note about the beeps. The answer is Yes, I can. I can post a class able to let you compose music... But this is a different question. If you will place such a question and tag me (here: @FaneDuru) I will supply the class and a piece of code to show you how to use  it.

Comment: @hugo:  It happened I found your question regarding the beeps. I suggested you to tag me (@FaneDuru) if need an answer... I place an answer there. Can you clarify the issue of ticking the accepted answer check box? Did you tick it and the you changed your mind? Not a problem with me, but I would like to understand why...

Comment: @hugo:  I can see you did it, but didn't you like my answer on beeping question?

Comment: sorry i did not change my mind, it was re-ticked by accident, im kind of new to coding and this sites as well. Trying to figure out how to tag you

Comment: But I told you: Use @FaneDuru inside the comment or at beginning, as I do in your case. I can receive here messages only **because I am the one posting the answer and we discuss on my post**. Otherwise, I would not receive any notification... So, could you  use the class I posted in the question regarding beeping?

Comment: to clyrify was this your answer link?http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx

Comment: @hugo: No! I posted an answer! A class code and instructions about how to use it... You can compose music using it... When I comment, post an answer, my user name (FaneDuru) appears at the end.

Comment: so you mean click on the FaneDuru?

Comment: No! You must write @FaneDuru at the beginning of your comment...

Comment: I wrote to you on FaneDuru